# jquery .html() output ALL elements other than 1

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors

I'm trying to output all first tds in all table rows, but `.html()` only outputs the first, rather than all.

From the jQuery website:

> *Description: Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of
>   matched elements.*

Relevant code:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var table1 = '<table><tr>';
  var data = $("#myTable tr:first-child").html();
  var table2 = '</tr></table>';
  var output = table1 + data + table2;
  $(".result").html(output);
});
```

When I change it to:

```
$("#myTable:first-child").html();
```

All matching elements are output, all trs, instead of just the first.

How can I output all first tds? And what does this rule of *only first matched element* mean? It seems only to apply sometimes...

http://jsfiddle.net/vaVe9/

Comment: The reason the second version outputs everything is because the browser implicitly wraps a `<tbody>` element around all the rows of the table. So the first child of the `<table>` is the `<tbody>`, not the first row.

Comment: Oops, that's not right. `$("#myTable:first-child")` doesn't select a child _of_ `#myTable`, it selects all elements with ID `myTable` that _are_ the first child of their parent. But if this matches anything, it returns a single element (the table) and then `.html()` returns all of its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how `.html()` works

you will need to iterate over the `td` you want.

```
var data = '';
$("#myTable tr td:first-child").each(function(){
   data+= $(this).html();
});
```

But you also need to keep in mind that `.html()` brings only the inner HTML of the selected element.

So you will need to wrap the result in a `td` yourself

```
var data = '';
$("#myTable tr td:first-child").each(function(){
   data+= '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
});
```

---

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/) states

> In an HTML document, `.html()` can be used to get the contents of any element. ***If the selector expression matches more than one element, only the first match will have its HTML content returned.***

Comment: this looks like what im looking for, but, why is the data = ''; empty? it doesnt seem to be working like that, cant completely understand what to do with data var

Comment: @user1721135, the code i posted should replace the `var data = $("#myTable tr:first-child").html();` in your code..

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var $table1 = $('<table><tr>')
  var $data = $("#myTable tr td:first-child");
    $.each($data, function () {
        $table1.append($(this));
    );
  $table1.append($('</tr></table>'));
  $(".result").append($table1);
});
```

Comment: this looks good, but why does it remove the items from the upper table and put them in the resul?

Comment: It's not removing anything from the upper table, it's building the table and then appending the table to result.